# Setting the CompoundStructure.EndCap is not working

Tags: revit-api

I am working on a Revit plugin using RevitAPI.

I create a new WallType by duplicating existing one. Then I edit the structure - adding new layers.
Also, I am setting the  OpeningWrapping to Both and I want to set the EndCap to Interior.

Unfortunately, the EndCap never changes and stays Exterior

```
structure.EndCap = EndCapCondition.Interior;
structure.OpeningWrapping = OpeningWrappingCondition.ExteriorAndInterior;
```

Does someone have any ideas about why it is not changing?

Thank you in advance!

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possible reasons.

Can you set the desired end cap behaviour manually through the user interface?

If not, it will normally not be possible to do so programmatically either.

Do you have an open transaction?

Can you commit other changes in it?

Are you applying other changes to the model that might conflict with the end cap condition?

Instead of asking you hundreds of questions, I suggest that you provide a minimal reproducible case:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b

p.s. the same question is also asked and further discussed here:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/compoundstructure-endcap-is-not-working/m-p/6898895